# how to access a class variable of outer class from inner class in ruby

Tags: ruby, class-variables

i have some code in Ruby here below:

```
class A
  @@lock = Monitor.new
  class B
    def method
      @@lock.synchronize
        puts "xxxxx"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

after running it throws an error which said that below:

**uninitialized class variable @@lock in A::B (NameError)**

if i want to know how to access the outer class A's class variable @@lock from inner class B's method, how to do it? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to access this class variable is via an accessor method

```
class A
   def self.lock
     @@lock ||= Monitor.new
   end

   class B
     def method
       A.lock.synchronize
         puts "xxxxx"
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can without defining an accessor.

Class `B` is lexically scoped inside of A, so its real name is A::B and various other things are different.

But it's not a child or any other sort of derived class, so it doesn't actually have any special rights to see private or protected or otherwise local elements of A.