# Access class variables in a modules class and instance methods

Tags: ruby

I have a module that contains both instance methods and class methods when included in a class. Both instance methods and class methods shall access class variables.

```
module MyModule
  @@a_class_variable = "lorem ipsum"

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def a_class_method
      @@a_class_variable << "abc"
    end
  end

  # Use it in constructor
  def initialize
    @@a_class_variable << "abc"
  end

  def an_instance_method
    @@a_class_variable << "abc"
  end
end
```

When I include `MyModule` in some class, the interpreter says: *NameError: uninitialized class variable @@a_class_method in MyModule::ClassMethods*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inside `MyModule::ClassMethods`, you're not inside `MyModule` and don't have access to `@@a_class_variable`. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688588/how-to-access-a-class-variable-of-outer-class-from-inner-class-in-ruby) a related question.

With an accessor, your code works fine :

```
module MyModule
  @@a_class_variable = "lorem ipsum"

  def self.a_class_variable
    @@a_class_variable
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def a_class_method
      MyModule.a_class_variable << " abc1"
    end
  end

  # Use it in constructor
  def initialize
    @@a_class_variable << " abc2"
  end

  def an_instance_method
    @@a_class_variable << " abc3"
  end
end

class MyObject
  include MyModule
end

my_object = MyObject.new
MyObject.a_class_method
p my_object.an_instance_method
#=> "lorem ipsum abc2 abc1 abc3"
```

As you noted in the comments, it exposes `@@a_class_variable` to the public.
Setting the method as `private` or `protected` wouldn't work in the above example, since `ClassMethods` and `MyModule` aren't related.

It might not be the cleanest solution, but you could use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-send) to access the private method :

```
module MyModule
  @@a_class_variable = 'lorem ipsum'

  module ClassMethods
    def a_class_method
      MyModule.send(:__a_class_variable) << ' abc1'
    end
  end

  # Use it in constructor
  def initialize
    @@a_class_variable << ' abc2'
  end

  def an_instance_method
    @@a_class_variable << ' abc3'
  end

  class << self
    def included(base)
      base.extend ClassMethods
    end

    private

    def __a_class_variable
      @@a_class_variable
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This makes it runnable indeed, but it exposes the class variable to the public. There isn't away to preserve the functionality and keep access to the class variable private, is it? Because when I'm in a class I can directly access any class variable both from instance and class methods.

Comment: I think now I understand the difference between def sef.something;end methods and methods in ClassMethods. I thought there wasn't a difference, but there is. I also looked up some parts of the code from rails (e.g. callbacks in ActiveSupport) and it looks like they implemented stuff exactly as you suggested (accessor method). I tried to understand it before, but I failed until now. All in all this is not what I've hoped for (read: the code is not as pretty as I hoped it could be), but that's not your fault so I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I'm by no mean a metaprogramming expert. There might very well be cleaner solutions.